# How do you set CLASSPATH to the Maven repository?

Tags: java, docker, maven

I have a Maven project, with some dependencies configured in the pom.xml.

Now, when I run `mvn package`, the dependencies are downloaded to `~/.m2/repository`. Eventually, this is a big directory tree with many directories and subdirectories that contain `jar` files.

I'm not working with any IDE - just running `mvn` and `java` from the command line.

Now, when I try running my project:

```
$ java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar App
```

I get a `NoClassDefFound` error - which I can understand since I'm trying to access dependency code in my code, and it's not in the classpath - there's nothing that defines the CLASSPATH to the `~/.m2/repository` directories.

So  my question is - how can I run my program from the command line and have the JVM use the dependencies from the `~/.m2/repository`?

I've been searching the web for this and surprisingly didn't find answers. What I've eventually managed to do is:

```
$ mvn dependency:build-classpath
```

then chain to this string the `./target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and then use this with the `-cp` option.

Is that the way to do it? It's pretty cumbersome...

Anyways, I can get away with using some IDE, that's fine. But what about packing my application in a Docker image? How is that done?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Run some classes from jar?

Comment: It's difficult to see what you're trying to do, but if you want to make a jar that's stand-alone, you need Maven Shade or the Maven Assembly plugin. If you don't want a lot of cruft accumulating in ~/.m2, you can change the value of localRepository to point at the /tmp directory

Comment: @tostao, I think it's pretty clear from the question. I'm trying to understand how should one run a java program that has dependencies that reside in the `~/.m2/repository` directory.

Comment: @YoavKlein No it is not clear because during runtime usually a local cache (`~/.m2/repository`) does not exist which means you should not use that as classpath furthermore in your local cache are too many files which you don't like to have on your classpath apart from having several jar's and classes duplication based on the subject that you have cached several versions of the same artifact... apart as already mentioned to run your app you should create an executable jar (aka shaded/jar-with-dependencies)....

Comment: It'd be pretty silly if you wouldn't be able to let Maven solve this for you, that's the whole reason for it existing - automation. And as always with Maven you have at least three options available to you. The more common method is to build a fat jar, which implies packaging all the classes from all the dependencies into one large jar. No head aches from having to lug around external dependencies, but this method can be kind of sketchy when it comes to licensing. Would this be acceptable to you?

Comment: @Gimby, I'm pretty new to Java and Maven, I'm just trying to understand what is the most straightforward way to do this. That's all

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are working *against* Maven, not *with* it. You should let Maven handle all classpath-related problems.

If you want to collect all dependency jars in a single folder, Maven can do that for you.

If you want to run or debug your application, whether from IDE or from command line, Maven can do that for you.

If you want to build a single JAR file containing all dependency classes, Maven can do that for you.

In short: Work with the tool, not against it.

Comment: that's a great motivation speech, can you be more practical?

Comment: Sure. Take the middle 3 sentences I wrote and put them into google. Plenty of articles have been written explaining how to do each of them.

Comment: As much as that is true, that does not make this a valid Stack Overflow answer. It doesn't answer anything.